# How do you create a histogram with a list of numbers?

Tags: python-3.x

pretend you have a list:
list = [23,25,22,31]

how would you be able to put these numbers into a histogram in python?

Comment: With x ticks like this q = ["Keep and Win",'','', "Keep and Lose",'', "Switch and Win",'','', "Switch and Lose"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a default dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

numbers = [23,25,22,31,23]

histogram = defaultdict(int)
for number in numbers:
  histogram[number] += 1
```

output:

```
defaultdict(int, {22: 1, 23: 2, 25: 1, 31: 1})
```

Note: A) Don't call your list "list" since its a reserved word. 
      B) I made the list of numbers have two 23s to demonstrate a histogram.

Comment: @DarshanD if this answers your question, may I suggest to mark the question as answered?